# Ubuntu 9.10 Guest Connection

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware-workstation

I am running Windows 7, VMWare Workstation 7.0.1 and have a Virtual Machine of Ubuntu 9.10.

The VM is installed and working correctly. The VMWare Tools are installed, I believe, it is greyed out on the VM menu.

I am unable to connect to the VM from other computers on my home network.

I am able to RDC to the Windows 7 computer with no problem.

I am using a NAT network for the Ubuntu VM, I am unable to try bridged, I get an error that there are no un-bridged network devices.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Saronaboun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need bridged to easily route traffic from your LAN, but if you need a quick hack, a local-only host will allow you to communicate with the VM.

NAT won't allow you to easily connect to your VM, though if I recall there may be a way to redirect ports ala a router in the networking options for the NAT.

Comment: Bridged is definitely what you want.  You could try something like "Restore Defaults" (link below) or maybe just add a second virtual NIC and try to set that one to bridged.

http://www.webf1.com/Blog/tabid/66/EntryId/8/VMWare-Workstation-Cannot-change-network-to-bridged-There-are-no-un-bridged-host-network-adapters.aspx